# Keyboard shortcut to edit breaks when there is an edit pending

Tags: feature-request, bug, keyboard-shortcuts

I press `e` to edit. As you can see there is an edit (1) pending:

[image]

I can't use `e` to open the dialogue. Why? Can I be able to please?